# Joomla newsletter template - clear:both alternative for outlook?

Tags: joomla, outlook, html-email

I have an image that floats and want the text afterwards to be underneath the image.
Here's what I have, it works for everything except the most popular mail client in a business environment (Outlook). I've tried wrapping them in

tags and would rather not have to use 
's as that could get messy in resizing situations.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit: I found a workaround which is to put the image into it's own row in case nobody has anything better**

```
<tr class="acyeditor_delete" title="Deletable">
            <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
            <td class="acyeditor_text w540" width="540">
                <img alt="picture" src="http://example.com/images/showcase/showcase_projekt.jpg" style=" height:300;  width:600; float:left; margin:5px; " />

                <h1 style="">My Firm - Die Branchenl&ouml;sung f&uuml;r Handwerk und Handel</h1>

                <p>
                <h3>XXX ist Ihr professionelles Werkzeug f&uuml;r alle Bereiche der t&auml;glichen B&uuml;roarbeit. Finden Sie die Daten Ihres Unternehmens an einer zentralen Stelle und gewinnen Sie mehr Zeit f&uuml;rs Wesentliche, indem Sie sich von xxx unterst&uuml;tzen lassen:</h3>
                </p>

            </td>
            <td class="w30" width="30"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You're coding your email template like it's a HTML landing page. If you want to support older email clients, you must use older coding standards. By this I mean each text, image or anything else has it's own row or column.

Comment: Also, text should be defined in your `td` with inline styling for the font family, size, colour, rather than using `h*` and `p` with classes.

Comment: Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.